# How to access variable outside of trans directive in email template?

Tags: email, email-templates, translate

I am trying to use a variable called reset_password_url and I cannot make it work. Below is what I have.

```
<a href="%reset_password_url">{{trans 'link' reset_password_url=$reset_password_url|raw}}</a>
```

How can I access reset_password_url outside of trans directive? Is there a way to have global variables in email templates?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you are firing that email. However reset_password_url will have been set in the variables for the particular email.

In System > Custom Variables you could potentially create something there.

Comment: This is actually the email fired when a new company is approved. I am using ahead works extension that fires the emails. So, A new company is created by user, admin approves it and when admin approves it, an email is sent and under System > Custom Variables, the reset_password_url is not there. What did u really mean when u said, "In System > Custom Variables you could potentially create something there."?

Comment: In the past, some clients have used this custom variable to insert {{ block code so that it could pull dynamic variables from a plugin.

The issue with it being the AheadWorks extension is that it's not a variable defined in their email sending.